# Plots with VS Code and R

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I can't get VS Code to display any type of R plots or graphs correctly.

I am using VS Code with the R Extension for Visual Studio Code, and my plots look like the one below:

[VS Code plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNYHi.jpg)

Is there anything that can be done to get better quality graphs? I currently use a different editor just to check graphs.

I've tried installing `httpgd`  and using that instead, within VS Code, but doesn't seem to have had any effect.

Comment: I managed to find an old blog post here: http://compbio.ucsd.edu/outputting-beautiful-jupyter-notebooks-r-kernel-edition/#html-output-mangled-graphics-text 

that seems to describe something similar to what's happening with my set-up. 

I've tried the suggested workaround:

`options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = c("text/plain", "image/png" ))`

and seems to work. 

Strangely, the author had problems with R Jupyter notebooks, while they work perfectly for me, and I'm having problems only on VS Code. I'm using the same kernel on Jupyter and VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

What can you do is increase the size of the plot.

The default size of R plots in VS Code may be too small, which can make them appear bad.

You can increase the size of your plot by adjusting the `fig.width` and `fig.height` options in your R code.

For example, you can set `options(repr.plot.width=10, repr.plot.height=6)` to make your plot 10 inches wide and 6 inches tall.

As an alternative, or in addition to above, what can be done, is :

You could use the correct resolution. Because, the resolution of your plot can also affect its quality.

By default, R plots in VS Code may have a low resolution, which you could increase by setting the `dpi option` while creating the plot.

For example, you can use `png("plot.png", dpi=300)` to create a PNG plot with a resolution of 300 dots per inch (or higher if need be).

Did you try these options?

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the suggestions but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding more parameters to your plot function? It might not be your resolution but the plot function itself. It may need more arguments to output a better chart.

I can see you are using plot() and then calling the data. You could add type = "b" to show points connected by lines. I would need to see more of the code to give a better answer.

Assuming your data is a matrix you may want to have a look into using matplot() instead.